# Xcode screensaver with openGL

Tags: xcode, opengl, screensaver

I am currently simply trying to build a simple screen saver in xcode 3.2 on osx 10.6.3 using an openGL view as described in this article: http://cocoadevcentral.com/articles/000089.php anyways even if I use the exact same code from the example all I see when testing the screen saver is a black screen. I looked in OSX Console if it tells me anything useful. the only thing I get is something like this:

> [0x0-0x1e01e].com.apple.systempreferences[629]    System
>   Preferences(629,0x7fff71071be0)
>   malloc: reference count underflow for
>   0x20057be80, break on
>   auto_refcount_underflow_error to
>   debug. System Preferences[629]    invalid
>   context

I have no idea what is wrong, so I would be glad if someone could tell me how to use openGL together with the screensaver template in xCode 3.2. Also, is there a way to make another target so I can preview the screensaver from within xCode?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The example on Cocoa Dev Central works just fine. The same error comes up for me, but as far as I can tell, that is not the reason why you're getting a black screen.

I had a similar problem because I wasn't correctly reinstalling the screen saver.

Make sure you quit System Preferences before reinstalling the screen saver. If you don't, the old screen saver will still be used, even when it asks you about overwriting it.

Comment: Thanks for saving me from ripping all my hair out.  I can't believe it silently fails to use the latest installed one -- total lack of finesse!